# Screen orientation made bottom buttons disappear

Tags: android, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

I have a very odd problem with the bottom navigation buttons. Our device has for a reason unknown to us set `ro.sf.hwrotation=270` in device properties list. With this settings everything works in portrait mode as intended (the boot logo/animation, system activities, our app, ...). What does not work is Miracast display which is, as you might have guessed it, incorrectly rotated.

So I have decided to look at it more closely and as the first step changed the property to `ro.sf.hwrotation=0`. Luckily this has fixed the Miracast issue, all system activities are still in portrait, our app ditto except this weird issue:

[image: portrait]

The buttons are gone. When rotated to landscape, again, everything is as it should except the buttons (now even stuck to the right side):

[image: landscape]

Can somebody give me a hint where to look? I can't see anything suspicious in the logs, no crash or exception.

Most likely the buttons are somehow weirdly rotated too but then again, why only the buttons? Is there something specific to them? If I revert the setting, everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is hardly a generic solution, it may help someone in the future: our device had tweaked not only the rotation setting but also `ro.sf.lcd_density` (changed from 160 to 188).

While experimenting I noticed that Overview (recent apps) button still somehow works, it's just hardly reachable (and not visible). So the button was there.

After yet another round of experiments and I noticed an innocent change of the density setting - and guess what, after reverting the value to 160 it worked again! For some reason we had decreased the LCD's width/height this way.

Of course, it comes with a price - now that we have increased LCD resolution, the device shows one button more and even in different order.

Accidentally, when I was about to start to live with different DPI/button arrangement I found this post: https://community.nxp.com/thread/384348#comment-831065. The author handles only one side of the display so this is a version to handle all four of them:

```
--- a/android4.2/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/NavigationBarView.java
+++ b/android4.2/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/NavigationBarView.java
@@ -415,7 +415,20 @@ public class NavigationBarView extends LinearLayout {
         for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
             mRotatedViews[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
-        mCurrentView = mRotatedViews[rot];
+        //mCurrentView = mRotatedViews[rot];
+
+        if (rot == Surface.ROTATION_0 && mVertical) {
+            mCurrentView = mRotatedViews[Surface.ROTATION_90];
+        } else if (rot == Surface.ROTATION_90 && !mVertical) {
+            mCurrentView = mRotatedViews[Surface.ROTATION_180];
+        } else if (rot == Surface.ROTATION_180 && mVertical) {
+            mCurrentView = mRotatedViews[Surface.ROTATION_270];
+        } else if (rot == Surface.ROTATION_270 && !mVertical) {
+            mCurrentView = mRotatedViews[Surface.ROTATION_0];
+        } else {
+            mCurrentView = mRotatedViews[rot];
+        }
+
         mCurrentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         mDeadZone = (DeadZone) mCurrentView.findViewById(R.id.deadzone);
```

After applying this patch I finally have a good solution - DPI is unchanged (i.e. 188), buttons are visible, HDMI is fixed and everything works as before.